# keeping a service running after shutting down the app

Tags: android, android-service

i'm trying to create an app that communicates with my localhost and search in a database.
I already make the connection and find the data, but i need to stay connected and send a notification if there's any changes in the table, but I can't figure it out how to keep the connection even when I close the app, because it closes everything, even the service.
The service doesn't stay open.

This is my Class:

```
public class SensorService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Starting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    boolean bandera = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Checking data...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    stopService(new Intent(this,SensorService.class));
    startService(new Intent(this,SensorService.class));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    startService(new Intent(this,SensorService.class));
}
}
```

Every time I close the app, the service execute one more time and no more.

Comment: Are you returning `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()` in your `Service`?

Comment: yup, but it still closing the service.

Comment: What device are you testing on? and what do you mean by "close the app"?

Comment: I mean terminate the application, I just added my class. I'm testing it in a Samsung J7

Comment: Post the manifest for your `<service>` please. Also, what do you mean by "every time I close the app, the service execute one more time and no more"? Please explain

Comment: How do you "close the app" or "terminate the app". Are you talking about "force stop" in Android settings->Apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the service to continue running after the app is closed, you need to call the startForeground(int, Notification) method from within the service. Android limits you to running longer running services in the background only as long as a notification is displayed to the user letting them know that a service is running (like a music player or a downloading service).

This is an intentional design constraint to ensure developers do not start services in the background that run indefinitely without the user being aware. Supply your own notification (can be anything) and you should be able to run the service in the background.

For more detailed information on this method, read it at: [startForeground(int, Notification)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))

Comment: Thanks, what I did was call onDestroy() at the end of startOnCommand, so every time the service is destroy it automatically start over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onTaskRemoved](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)) and restart the service if needed.

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
       super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
       //restart your service
}
```

Please note that if you use onTaskRemoved, start your service as not sticky so it won't be restarted.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```